# Does Javascript filter preserve order?

Tags: javascript

I looked at the documentation and while looking at examples it looks like filter preserves order of the original list (though it returns a new one). Can I rely on that?

[Ecmascript spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.20)

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Neither of these reference preserving order. Should I just assume I can't rely on preserved order?

Comment: `filter calls callbackfn once for each element in the array, in **ascending order** `

Comment: The ECMAScript spec that you linked very clearly describes a preserved order.

Comment: @squint After reading Oriol's answer I don't think it is immediately obvious from the spec.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Yes. From the [spec](https://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.20),

> - Let *selected* be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of *callbackfn* with *T* as the this value and argument list containing *kValue*, *k*, and *O*.
> - If [ToBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2)(*selected*) is **true**, then
>
>   - Call the [[DefineOwnProperty]] internal method of *A* with arguments [ToString](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.8)(*to*), [Property Descriptor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.10) {[[Value]]: *kValue*, [[Writable]]: **true**, [[Enumerable]]: **true**, [[Configurable]]: **true**}, and **false**.
>   - Increase *to* by 1.

So the items in the returned array have the same order than in the original one.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, the `.filter()` method returns a new array copy (minus the filtered elements), preserving the same order as the initial array.

The order of the elements is one of the main feature of a array.