# Editing and deleting a card in semantic UI using react.

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4, semantic-ui

I'm trying to add user functionality to my cards. I have already created the cards and would like the user to be able to edit the data inside the card and delete the card entirely if they wish.

Deleting should look something like this 
[example of deleting a card using jquery](https://www.bootply.com/5Abr3Qa979) . I'm new to react and am good at jquery. I was wondering what the steps were to transform that code into react code. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="ui cards">

        {
          sampleUsers.map(user =>
            <div className = "card">
              <div className = "content">
                <div className = "header > {user.name} </div>
                <div className = "description"> 
                  {user.description}
                </div>

                <div clasName = "extra content">
                  <div className = "ui two buttons">
                    <div className = "ui basic green button">Edit</div>
                    <div className = "ui basic red button">Delete</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          )
        }
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit hard to answer without seeing how you are storing `sampleUsers`, but basically, you would want to add a click handler to the Delete button, remove the item from `sampleUsers` and then rerender.

Here is an idea of one way to go about it to get you started. I haven't tested it, but hope it helps!

```
class Users extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      sampleUsers: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'John',
          description: 'A nice guy'
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Jane',
          description: 'A nice gal'
        }
     ]
   }
 }

 handleDeleteUser: (id) => {
   const sampleUsers = this.state.sampleUsers.filter(user => user.id !== id)
   this.setState({ sampleUsers });
 }

 render() {
   return (
     <div class="ui cards">

      {
        this.state.sampleUsers.map(user =>
          <div className = "card">
            <div className = "content">
              <div className = "header > {user.name} </div>
              <div className = "description"> 
                {user.description}
              </div>

              <div clasName="extra content">
                <div className="ui two buttons">
                  <div className="ui basic green button">Edit</div>
                  <div 
                    className="ui basic red button"
                    onClick={() => this.handleDeleteUser(user.id)}
                  >
                    Delete
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        )
      }
    </div>
   )
 }
```

**UPDATE**
As a commenter pointed out, there is a Semantic React wrapper library you might want to look at. It doesn't really address your question, but good to pass along https://react.semantic-ui.com

Comment: Thank you so much! That is exactly how I stored sampleUsers.

Comment: Array.filter is not safe as it will `shuffle` all elements and it will not preserve the correct order, it will cause blinking UI and shuffling all cards on every click. I've posted correct solution in my answer

Comment: @MilosMosovsky are you sure? I don't pretend to be an expert on Array.filter, but I don't see any indication that it does shuffle the order. I use filter quite frequently in my apps and have never observed that behavior (though I know that it is not necessarily proof) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712160/does-javascript-filter-preserve-order

Comment: @torylor great! Welcome to React. I hope you enjoy working with it. As MilosMosovsky mentioned, there is also a Semantic React wrapper lib that you might want to consider. I will add it to my answer for completeness

Answer (score 2):

At first there is native support for React by `semantic-ui` https://react.semantic-ui.com/introduction so I would advice you to use it.

Secondly I created a sandbox for you

[image: Edit n43z9w3o0]

Live view: https://n43z9w3o0.codesandbox.io/