# Deleting item (card) from react array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, events, methods

I'm struggling on how to write a delete method to delete a card from this view using the delete button in the kebab dropdown.

https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-worker-0y5vm

I've looked at all the questions on here about how to remove an item from a react array, but I'm declaring my array later (rather than in the state) with:

```
{Array.apply(0, Array(1)).map((x, i) => ( ...
```

All the answers to those  questions I've seen use:

```
.map(item => ( ... `
```

with the `.splice` or the `.filter` method, neither of which I've been able to figure out, since I'm also using `Array.apply` with some other parameters `map` needs to take in.

For example, this didn't work but it's exactly what I need to do: [Editing and deleting a card in semantic UI using react.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109178/editing-and-deleting-a-card-in-semantic-ui-using-react)

How can I get the delete button to work using either `.filter` or `.splice` with the way I create my array currently?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you make some flags in the state?

Comment: Hello, firstly You should create external component name - Item for example, next You need some list, which will apply all Item Component, when you have this structure you can add CRUD operations - Also Your code explicit breaks DRY rule

Comment: @worldNeverSaysHelloBack - how do you want the UX to be?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
state.filter( item => item.id !== action.payload);
```

`action.payload` could be whatever you send with an onClick or other event handler that matches the item.id or what you choose to delete.