# How can I update multiple checkbox values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After fetching all data from backend, I'm grouping the data by Date wise below is the code for it

```
 const [transactionsList, setTransactionsList] = useState<TransactionList | any>();
 const [groupedTransactionsList, setGroupedTransactionsList] = useState<TransactionsByDate[] | null>(null);
  const [selectedTransaction, setSelectedTransaction] = useState<any>([]);
      
const response = await postAPIRequestCall(`${API_URL_PREFIX}/cards/transactionList`,
              { AccountNumber: res.encryptedAccountNumber });
            if (response) {
              setTransactionsList(response.data);
              groupByDate(response.data);
            }
```

Below is the logic to group all date by date wise and storing the value to `groupedTransactionsList`

```
 const groupByDate = (response: TransactionList) => {
    of(...response.transactionDetails).pipe(
      groupBy((transaction: any) => transaction.transactionDate),
      mergeMap((group$) => group$.pipe(reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, cur], [`${group$.key}`]))),
      map((arr) => ({ date: arr[0], transactions: arr.slice(1) } as TransactionsByDate)),
      toArray(),
    ).subscribe((p) => setGroupedTransactionsList(p));
  };
```

Inside the render method, I'm displaying the data by date wise

```
{groupedTransactionsList?.map((
              {
                date,
                transactions,
              },
              key,
            ) => (
              <div key={date}>
                <div className="date pb-1">{moment(date).format('ddd D MMM')}</div>
                {transactions.map((
                  transaction,
                  index,
                ) => (
                  <div className="col-12 content" key={transaction.transactionReferenceNumber}>
                    <div className="col-11 pl-0">
                      <Checkbox
                        checked={transaction.isChecked}
                        onChange={(name, vlaue, e) => handleCheckboxOnChange(
                          transaction,
                          e.target.checked,
                        )}
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                ))}
              </div>
            ))}
```

On selection of each transaction, I calling this method handleCheckboxOnChange,

```
const handleCheckboxOnChange = (
    transactionDetails: TransactionDetail,
    isCheckeds: boolean,
  ) => {
    transactionsList.transactionDetails
      .filter((item: TransactionDetail) => item.transactionReferenceNumber === transactionDetails.transactionReferenceNumber)
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      .map((item: TransactionDetail) => item.isChecked = isCheckeds);

    const selectedTransactions = transactionsList.transactionDetails
      .filter((item: TransactionDetail) => item.isChecked === true);
    setSelectedTransaction(selectedTransactions);

    groupByDate(transactionsList);
  };
```

Everything works fine and I'm getting expected results, but the problem is I'm calling `groupByDate` every time when user clicks on the check box. which is bad,

How do optimize my code & logic. Please guide me

Comment: [filter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39712200/13405106) preserve the order so you can use .filter only instead of .map in handleCheckboxOnChange  `.filter((item: TransactionDetail) => item.transactionReferenceNumber === transactionDetails.transactionReferenceNumber && item.isChecked = isCheckeds)`

Comment: `Parsing error: ',' expected.eslint` I get this error while calling the above method